# Texture difficulties in Three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, collada

I'm still experiencing some difficulties with the texture on my model. First I was trying the collada model with three.js r50, now I'm trying the .obj model with three.js r56 and still getting some black lines on my texture, Like the seems of the texture. Can someone help me understand what is happening? Here is my two examples:

http://victorribeiro.com/modelo3Dobj/ (three.js r56 - model .obj)

http://victorribeiro.com/modelo3D/ (three.js r50 - model collada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only seeing the black lines you refer to when viewing a face at grazing angles.

What fixed it for me was setting `texture.aniostropy` in the loader callback function like so:

```
var map = object.children[0].material.map;
map.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
```

This, of course, is machine specific.

Otherwise, I do not see anything wrong with your model.

three.js r.56

Comment: Could you please help once again telling me where to put this code inside my code?

Comment: You can put it right after `scene.add( object )` in your loader callback function.